# Recover three Linux partitions shown as unallocated after repartitioning with Windows app AOMEI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Help me please.
I have done something stupid, I've changed the partions without having any backup.

I have a Windows alongside Ubuntu 19.10 and I've resized the windows partition (c drive) from 100GB to 50GB using "AOMEI partition assistant" software in Windows. In process after some step it booted to the temp boot which software provided to complete the process.

After that I restarted the laptop. Grub menu was gone.
It booted to grub's terminal.

I booted into a live iso of ubutbu 18.04 and it shows my Linux partitions as one unallocated partion.
All of my data is in /home partition.
What should I do????

[image: Screenshot of gParted]

It's my first time on ask Ubuntu And it's panic faze, so I'm sorry if it's not a well asked question.

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to this post : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1154829&p=7251243#post7251243

I've found my lost partitions using TestDisk,
here is testdisk output after quick search:

```
TestDisk 7.2-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, January 2020
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 512 GB / 476 GiB - CHS 488386 64 32

Warning: the current number of heads per cylinder is 64
but the correct value may be 8.
You can use the Geometry menu to change this value.
It's something to try if
- some partitions are not found by TestDisk
- or the partition table can not be written because partitions overlap.
```

and after I press Enter:

```
TestDisk 7.2-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, January 2020
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 512 GB / 476 GiB - CHS 488386 64 32
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>D FAT32                    1   0  1   260  63 32     532480 [EFI System Partition] [SYSTEM_DRV]
 D HPFS - NTFS            277   0  1 51991  63 32  105912320 [Windows-SSD]
 D Linux                103386   0  1 127799  63 32   49999872
 D Linux                127800   0  1 471760  63 32  704432128
 D Linux Swap           471761   0  1 487385  63 32   32000000
 D HPFS - NTFS          487386   0  1 488385  63 32    2048000 [WINRE_DRV]
```

3 (Linux) lost partitions are shown, and navigating on them shows:

```
Structure: Ok.
```

and by pressing "P" I can browse my data.
the largest Linux partition is my /Home partition which holds all of my data.
**now, how should I proceed?**
(since the data is too important to me I dont want to risk it by doing any wrong steps).

Comment: Post a screenshot of GParted. A really clear one. We need to be able to read the text.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for you'r respond, screenshot link added.

Comment: @Danyal.e.p If you post your answer as an answer to your question, you will increase your chances of getting upvotes. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for contributing.